# Eclipse debugging a variable

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

While debugging a variable in Eclipse that takes "true" but the same takes "false" when i run the code in Eclipse. What are all the possible reasons for this scenario?

Thx

Comment: Sorry I am not able to show my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application runs multiple threads (or receives op. system callbacks from another thread or something similar), it is possible, that your application contains race conditions: depending on the execution order different values get assigned.

Using a debugger can change execution times to bring forth the other order.

Comment: Thx ...this is the exact scenario I got up with.As per you "Using a debugger can change execution times to bring forth the other order."How to achieve this in ECLIPSE.Please advice

Comment: I don't know of any IDE function that explicitly helps dealing with race conditions. Maybe you could try to (1) synchronize between the threads, or (2) use volatile/etc. variables to avoid this mess.

Answer (score 1):

Several possibilities come to mind.  My guess is that your launch configurations are different, and that influences the initialization of the variable.

Comment: This might be reason.But my case is not this.Thx